# What is the correct syntax to get a result from two parameters using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

The following expression works for one parameter and does not work with two, what is correct syntax?

```cs
return await _repository.GetPagedListAsync(
    predicate: c => c.L_Name.Contains(_lname) , c => c.F_Name.Contains(_fname),
    pageIndex: page,
    pageSize: limit,
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken
);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `predicate` is invalid. You must either have a single statement that returns a boolean value:

```cs
predicate: param => param == 5
```

Or you must include a block statement with a boolean `return` value:

```cs
predicate: param =>
{
    count += 1;
    return param > count;
}
```

---

In your case, you can join both statements into one inline statement using [the logical AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) (`&&`):

```cs
return await _repository.GetPagedListAsync(
    predicate: c => c.L_Name.Contains(_lname) && c.F_Name.Contains(_fname),
    pageIndex: page,
    pageSize: limit,
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken
);
```